# in Flex, how do I get the label for CheckBox to align to bottom?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

This is really annoying me, but if I do

```
<mx:CheckBox label="Checkbox" />
```

the label is slightly off the vertical center. I haven't found anything that relates to vertical alignment of the label in checkbox. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to adjust the leading of your font, so in your label style, you'll want to have something like:

```
CheckBox{
    leading: 0;
}
```

Note that 0 may not be the correct value for your font, it may be 1 or even -2 on some fancy fonts.

Basically your issue is that the height of the text in your check box is calculated to include the leading (spacing between lines of text), whose default value is 2. Since Checkboxes generally don't have two lines of text, you can set this value to 0, and it'll draw your check box correctly. You can also specify leading in the mxml tag or via `setStyle` but as *leading* is a style, the best place to set it is in the css.

Comment: Setting leading to -2 seemed to align it correctly.. except it wasn't displaying letters like "g" correctly. Basically bottom of 'g' was cut. I ended up extending CheckBox and in updateDisplayList move the textField down 2 pixel. Hopefully this is fixed in Flex 4...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extending the CheckBox you can check this solution:
http://flexdeveloping.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/checkbox-height-and-label-vertical-alignment/

Comment: This solution seems to only be available in Flex 4.